# How to add objects to a List<> class?

Tags: c#, list

This code works:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    List<Class> classList= new List<Class>();
    classList.Add(new Class { "set properties" });
}
```

But what about the code below, when the object (aclass) is filled and comes from the outside of the MyMethod:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    List<Class> classList= new List<Class>();
    Class class = (Class)aclass       // "aclass : of type Object"
    classList.Add(class);
}
```

All the items in the list will be the same, as the last item.
But I want to add another objects to the list and then use them in another place.

Comment: How does it "not work"? Does it throw a `System.InvalidCastException`?

Comment: it works. But "All the items in the list will be the same, as the last item." I want to add another objects to the list.

Comment: The `aclass` is not of `object` type and your code is not relevant for the problem

Comment: change variable name and type casting should be same i.e aclass should typeof(Class)

Comment: You need to create a new object for each element in the list you want to add. You are just adding the same object over and over, and that object is a reference type, so modifications to that object are reflected in each reference to the object, i.e. each element in the list. See marked duplicates for additional info.

Comment: Each time, it is filled with new properties, but all items in the list have the the last properties of the object.

Comment: _" it is filled with new properties"_ -- there is no such thing as "filling with new properties". You haven't bothered to include a good [mcve], but it seems clear enough that your "fill with new properties" is just code that assigns new values to the properties of an existing object. You've only called `new Class()` once, assigned that to `aclass` and/or `class`, and then repeatedly changed the property values before adding the object to the list. You can't do that. You have to call `new Class()` for each new object you want to add to the list.

Comment: @PeterDuniho   Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score -1):

Here is Simple way to do so

```
List<Class> classList= new List<Class>();

if(aclass = typeof(Class)){
 classList.Add(aclass);
}
```

Comment: My object comes from the outside of the code (method).

Comment: please check now